# How to insert a random delay for connection request (tomcat)?

Tags: tomcat

On Tomcat8.5, I am operating a certain Java application, which invokes C++ code via JNI that includes a long Critical Sections (takes approximately 1 second). Therefore, if the server receives many (~1000 or more) requests from clients at once by accident, the JVM invokes many worker threads and it causes very long delay for client (several minutes).

To prevent situation above, how can I configure the server (Windows 2016), Tomcat, or JVM parameters?

The Java application and C++ (DLL) is black-box and it is not possible to modify their code for me.

My idea is somehow to insert delays (of random milliseconds) for incoming requests before Tomcat's worker threads accept them so that critical section will be broken up.

Please give me any suggestions as for not only network, but also configurations of Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

That isn't going to work. If ~1000 requests arrive at once and processing each request requires a ~1s critical section there is no getting around that it is going to take ~1000 seconds to process all of those requests. A delay a few milliseconds isn't going to help.

Without knowing the details of what that DLL is doing, it is difficult to provide suggestions for alternative approaches that might work.